# How can I map the node index in pytorch geometric graph?

Tags: python, networkx, pytorch-geometric

I'd like to mapping node index to the original name in pytorch geometric graph for extracting node embedding.

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import pandas as pd

data = {'source': ['123', '2323', '545', '4928', '398'],
       'target': ['2323', '398', '958', '203', '545']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
#source target
#0  123 2323
#1  2323    398
#2  545 958
#3  4928    203
#4  398 545
```

Note that I inserted additional nodes without edges.

```py
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target')
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, { n:str(n) for n in G.nodes()})

G.add_nodes_from(['1', '309', '6749'])
G.number_of_nodes()
```

Then I converted the networkx graph to pytorch geometric graph.

```py
from torch_geometric.utils.convert import from_networkx

pyg_graph = from_networkx(G)
print(pyg_graph)
#Data(edge_index=[2, 10], num_nodes=10)
```

Finally, I get the below edge index that need to mapping index to name.
(It is normal situation that PyG graph has bidirectional graph automatically)

```py
pyg_graph.edge_index
# tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#         [1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5]])

# Expected result
# 123   0
# 2323  1
# 398   2
# 545   3
# 958   4
# 4928  5
# 203   6
# 1     7 
# 309   8
# 6749  9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the node label as an attribute, pyg_graph keeps the label as a feature.

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G,{n:{'label':n} for n in G.nodes()})
pyg_graph = from_networkx(G)
print(pyg_graph.label)
# or for detailed print
for node,lbl in enumerate(pyg_graph.label):
    print(lbl, node)
```